# Getting New Google Site Published URL from Drive.Files.list

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-sites

So I'm working on something to list all sites within our domain.
I can get this using Drive.File.list, and that's fine. I can query and get the name of the site and the owners email, however, I can't figure a way to get the sites published URL.

This is the core of what I have so far:

```html
function getNewSites() {
  var responses = Drive.File.list({
    corpus: "DEFAULT",
    maxResults: 1,
    q: 'mimeType="application/vnd.google-apps.site" and title="Test Site"',
    fields: "items/owners/emailAddress,items/title"
  });
  Logger.log(responses);
}
```

Which returns:

```
{
 "items": [
  {
   "title": "Test Site",
   "owners": [
    {
     "emailAddress": "email@address.co.uk"
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```

You can get edit URLs and embed links etc, but I can't figure out how to get the published URL at all (Is it's not the file name that is used in that URL)
The URL in that example is `https://sites.google.com/domain.co.uk/testsaaaaa/home`

'testsaaaaa' isn't referenced anywhere that I can see in the payload.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure this can be done with the Drive API, since the Drive API is more or less about generic file properties and not document-specific things. I checked both v2 and v3 using the Google APIs Explorer, and was unable to obtain any sort of "published" information.

[Drive v2 demo link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v2/drive.files.list?q=mimeType%253D%2522application%252Fvnd.google-apps.site%2522&fields=*&_h=3&)

[Drive v3 demo link](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/drive/v3/drive.files.list?q=mimeType%253D%2522application%252Fvnd.google-apps.site%2522&fields=*&_h=2&)

Unfortunately, the Google Sites API is not (yet?) compatible with the "new" Google Sites. With [old sites](https://developers.google.com/sites/docs/1.0/reference#feed_ListSites), you could access this published URL with a web address mapping request: https://developers.google.com/sites/docs/1.0/developers_guide_protocol#WebAddressMappings

You can authorize the Google Sites API by editing your Apps Script manifest file to include the scope `"https://sites.google.com/feeds"`

This is an example script (that again, will only work for "classic" Google Sites:

```
function ClassicSitesLister() {
  // https://developers.google.com/sites/docs/1.0/reference#feed_ListSites
  const url = 'https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site?with-mappings=true'; // replace final 'site' with custom domain
  const options = {
    Authorization: "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()
  };
  const resp = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, {headers: options});
  const content = resp.getContentText(); // gets XML content
  console.log({message: "Classic Sites data", xmlContent: content});
}
```

And the logged data is similar to this:

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<feed xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:openSearch='http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/' 
     xmlns:batch='http://schemas.google.com/gdata/batch' xmlns:gd='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005' xmlns:gs='http://schemas.google.com/spreadsheets/2006' 
     xmlns:thr='http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0' xmlns:sites='http://schemas.google.com/sites/2008' 
     xmlns:dc='http://purl.org/dc/terms' xmlns:gAcl='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007'>
  <id>https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site</id>
  <updated>2018-10-08T16:09:52.181Z</updated>
  <title>Site</title>
  <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#feed' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site'/>
  <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/g/2005#post' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site'/>
  <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site?with-mappings=true'/>
  <generator version='1' uri='http://sites.google.com'>Google Sites</generator>
  <openSearch:startIndex>1</openSearch:startIndex>
  <entry gd:etag='&quot;KXsmYD5aEw..&quot;'>
    <id>https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site/......</id>
    <updated>2015-08-25T20:44:44.336Z</updated>
    <app:edited xmlns:app='http://www.w3.org/2007/app'>2015-08-25T20:44:44.336Z</app:edited>
    <title>......</title>
    <summary>......</summary>
    <link rel='alternate' type='text/html' href='https://sites.google.com/site/....../'/>
    <link rel='http://schemas.google.com/acl/2007#accessControlList' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/acl/site/site/.....'/>
    <link rel='edit' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site/.....?with-mappings=true'/>
    <link rel='self' type='application/atom+xml' href='https://sites.google.com/feeds/site/site/......'/>
    <sites:siteName>......</sites:siteName>
    <sites:theme>......</sites:theme>
  </entry>
</feed>
```

In the above feed, the `<link rel='alternate'>`'s `href` attribute is the published URL for that particular site. Per the linked example, if you alias to a custom domain that should appear as its own entry under `<link rel='webAddressMapping' href='....">`, of which there may be multiple.