# List visible "New" Google Sites in domain

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client, google-sites

I am attempting to use the Drive API and the Google Java client library to retrieve the "new version" Google Sites that an individual user in our domain has access to.

I am able to retrieve sites, but only if a user has "edit" permissions for the site. If I set a user to "only view published site," that site will not show up in the results (see code snippet below).

I am also having difficulty retrieving the published site url from the service. Any help is appreciated.

```
public Response getFiles(@PathParam("userId") String userId) throws  GeneralSecurityException, IOException  {
    Drive service = GoogleServices.getDriveService(userId);

    Files.List list = service.files().list()
    .setOrderBy("name")
    .setQ("mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.site'")
    .setFields("nextPageToken, files(*)")
    .setPageSize(100);

    for (File fileObj : files.getFiles()) {
       System.out.println("fileobj:" + fileObj.toPrettyString());
    }
}

public static Drive getDriveService(String userEmail) throws GeneralSecurityException,IOException {
  HttpTransport httpTransport = new NetHttpTransport();
  JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
  GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
      .setTransport(httpTransport)
      .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
      .setServiceAccountId(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
      .setServiceAccountScopes(Arrays.asList(DriveScopes.DRIVE))
      .setServiceAccountUser(userEmail)
      .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(
          new java.io.File(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_PKCS12_FILE_PATH))
      .build();

  Drive service = new Drive.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory, null)
    .setApplicationName("Drive Service")
    .setHttpRequestInitializer(credential).build();
  return service;
}
```

Comment: You can check this SO post answered by tehhowch - [Getting New Google Site Published URL from Drive.Files.list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703958/getting-new-google-site-published-url-from-drive-files-list).